# Why boost::geometry::distance with model::d2::point_xy<float> returns a double not a float?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-geometry

I compared performance of `boost::geometry::distance` on `model::d2::point_xy<float>` arguments with an equivalent straightforward 2D implementation:

```
struct Point {
  float x, y;
  float distance(const Point& p) const {return sqrt((x-p.x)*(x-p.x)+(y-p.y)*(y-p.y));}
};
```

(see the whole benchmark at http://rextester.com/NTOVR83857). I found that boost version is consistently slower across all major C++ compilers:

- 1.77x for gcc
- 1.47x for clang
- 1.51x for vc++

I tried the same benchmark with `double` point coordinates, where boost performed without overhead. I noticed that `boost::geometry::distance` with `model::d2::point_xy<float>` arguments returns a `double`, which seems to be the reason of slowdown. Why it is not returning a `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since boost is using templates, it needs to make sure that the return type has sufficient precision.  Imagine if the input Points had integer values for X and Y - the result needs more than integer precision.  Also, a result of `float` would be insufficient precision if the input Point used double values for X and Y.  So, it appears that `double` is chosen as the catch-all for adequate precision.

The rationales for the design of the distance template are given here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html

Comment: I was expecting the return type to depend on argument type: `double` for `model::d2::point_xy<double>`, `float` for `model::d2::point_xy<float>`, etc. Shouldn't `distance_result<G1, G2>::type` handle that?

Comment: If it did, then it would return `int` for `model::d2::point_xy<int>`, which would essentially be "broken" - too little precision.

Comment: _essentially be "broken" - too little precision_ Not necessarily, it depends on application. Also, choosing `double` as a default doesn't provide enough accuracy for 64-bit and longer integers.

Comment: For "generic" usage, `double` was determined to be the "best fit" return type.  Yes, it isn't as fast as your home-brew method.  Templates are not always the best fit for everyone's use.  I think you have your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The return type depends on the strategy: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html#geometry.design.return_type.

This leads me to think you can specify the calculation type via the strategy explicitly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/886660f50140ed34)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/distance.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/strategies/distance.hpp>


int main() {
    using namespace boost::geometry;
    using P = model::d2::point_xy<float>;
    using V = traits::coordinate_type<P>::type;

    std::cout << "Coordinate type:  " << typeid(V).name() << "\n";

    P a, b;
    std::cout << "Calculation type: " << typeid(default_distance_result<P, P>::calculation_type).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Result type:      " << typeid(default_distance_result<P, P>::type).name()             << "\n";

    using S = strategy::distance::pythagoras<V>;
    std::cout << "Calculation type: " << typeid(distance_result<P, P, S>::calculation_type).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Result type:      " << typeid(distance_result<P, P, S>::type).name()             << "\n";

    static_assert(boost::is_same<distance_result<P, P, S>::type, float>::value, "oops");
}
```

Prints (piped through `c++filt -t`):

```
Coordinate type:  float
Calculation type: boost::geometry::strategy::distance::pythagoras<void>::calculation_type<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<float, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<float, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >
Result type:      double
Calculation type: boost::geometry::strategy::distance::pythagoras<float>::calculation_type<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<float, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<float, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >
Result type:      float
```

Beware of result precision that might get clipped because of limited precisions. This is very much a precision/storage efficiency trade off.

I actually expect the best performance to happen with `double` everywhere (instead of `float`) especially with full optimization on modern CPU instruction sets.

Comment: How do you use it to force `float` return of `distance` on `model::d2::point_xy<float>`?

Comment: I show it in the code! Use `pythagoras<float>` strategy... (See my added caveat at the bottom though)

Comment: _I show it in the code!_  Yes, you do, but I can't see. You exposition is too high level for template averse audience. Can you add a line, which actually calls `distance` and returns `float`?

Comment: _I actually expect the best performance to happen with double everywhere_ It won't due to 2x bandwidth penalty for `double` and 2x performance advantage of float SIMD operations.

Comment: Oh well. Always measure anyways. I was under the impression that the vectorized instruction sets favoured double. I could well be wrong. Also, I didn't consider bandwidth bottlenecks